# Including OpenCV native library headers in Android Studio

Tags: opencv, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I can't get my C code using native OpenCV to work in Android Studio. OpenCV through the Java wrappers work, but I have been banging my head against this for the last couple of days trying to get it to work with the native libraries. (I have some C code that depends on OpenCV that I need to use in my project)

To pin down the problem I'm trying to get the tutorial-2-mixedprocessing OpenCV sample project to build in AS.

OpenCV is in a separate module in the project, with the shared libraries (.so, .a files) in jniLibs, and the headers are in jni. The application module has a dependency on it. See the image below for the sample code and result when building.

[image: Android Studio screenshot]

Apparently the headers are not found?
I have tried adding the -I flag to CFlags in android.ndk in the gradle file with no success:

```
CFlags.add("-I${file("path/to/opencv-android-sdk/native/jni/include/")}".toString())
```

I have also tried placing the headers in the app module jni folder, as well as using different versions of Android Studio and Gradle.

I keep finding outdated solutions and conflicting information online, it seems like the build system in Android Studio is still changing a lot between versions. I'm also new to both Android development and NDK, so apologies if this is a stupid question. All I really need is a working sample that I can adapt to my project.

What am I missing?

Project structure:

[image: Project structure]

Project gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

OpenCV library module gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.library'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 21
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled = false
                proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.txt'))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Application module gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId = "org.opencv.samples.tutorial2"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 21
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
        }

        ndk {
            moduleName = "mixed_sample"
            //CFlags.add("-I${file("path/to/opencv-android-sdk/native/jni/include/")}".toString())
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled = false
                proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.txt'))
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':openCVLibrary2411')
}
```